# Remove first menu item separator wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to insert "/" as separators before all menu items except the first. I managed to insert the separators but cannot figure out how to remove the first one only. Here's the css:

```
.nav li a:before {content:' / ';}
.nav li a:first-child:before {content:'';}
```

This would make sense to me, but the second line of code removes all separators and not the first. I also tried the following:

```
.nav li:before {content:' / ';}
.nav li:first-child:before {content:'';}
```

Now the first separator was removed, but all of the separators were above and between the menu links. Im using the bones starter theme.
Please help a noob out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.nav li a:before {content:' / ';}
.nav li:first-child a:before {content:'';}
```

The `<a/>` is always the first-child of the `<li />` so you need to get the first `<li/>`